# determine hg default url from a perl script

Tags: perl, mercurial

How would one determine a hg repository's default url from a perl script?

(the url that shows up on line 1 if you write "hg in")

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7310017/edit) to add some sample data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply run `hg paths default` and it will print the path.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to running `hg paths default` (if, for example, you don't actually have mercurial installed) would be to look at the `hgrc` file found in the repository itself:

```
c:\> cd MyRepo
c:\> type .hg\hgrc
[paths]
default = o:\HG\MyRepo
```

Yes, that's Windows command-prompt stuff right there, but you get the idea - you can `cat .hg/hgrc` and look at the `default` option in the `[paths]` section.